# Aborting XNA main thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, xna

I'm currently shifting a game that I created from XNA's sequential approach (consecutive calls of Updates and Draws) into a multi-threaded approach.

I've already succeeded in moving game updates and draws to other tasks/threads. The only issue I'm having is figuring out how to abort the main XNA thread (the class that extends the Game class) because I literally have empty `Update()` and `Draw()` methods.

When I attempt to abort that thread via:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
```

as the last line of the `Initialize()` method of the `Game` class, the entire application terminates. So, is there a way to terminate the main thread of XNA and still have the game window executing? The reason I'm trying to terminate this thread is that I don't want it to impact the performance of the game by executing empty Update/Draw.

Comment: If you don't want the main thread will call `Update` and `Draw` you can at least set `Enable = Visible = false;`

Comment: @pinckerman That only works for (`Drawable`)`GameComponent`s. There's no such option for the main loop itself.

Comment: @AndrewRussell You are right, my fault.

Answer (score 2):

Well - you *really* don't want to abort the main thread. That thread owns the window XNA is using for display, and **you can only do input on the main thread** (that is: `Mouse.GetState`, `Keyboard.GetState`, etc).

Calling `Abort` on it is equivalent to raising a `ThreadAbortException`, which will bubble up and (in the default `Program.cs` template) clean up your game instance (see the `using` statement).

**Consider simply using that main thread as the thread responsible handling `Update` or `Draw`.**

---

But if you've *really* got your heart set on doing this, you can stop XNA from pumping updates with this code:

```
Application.Idle = null;
```

(Requires referencing and using `System.Windows.Forms`.)

You can perhaps use `Game.RunOneFrame` or `Tick` if you wanted to continue using functionality in `Game`. No idea about the wonderful ways in which XNA might explode if you tried to call these methods off-thread.

If you don't use them, you'll need to provide your own timing code, you'll need to call `FrameworkDispatcher.Update` regularly (required for audio).

Either way you'll have to figure out a way to perform input on the main thread. The Win32 message loop will still be running on that thread (or, rather, blocking), so you'll need to hook into that to do your input.

Comment: Thanks. Another reason for using XNA's main thread is that you cannot reset the graphics device from a different thread other than the main one! I just found this out when I got an "undefined" exception when attempting to reset it. According to the MSDN:    A call to Reset fails if made on a different thread than the one used to create the GraphicsDevice being reset